# Error with AMPL script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ampl

here there is a AMPL script (TSP problem with costs) but I don't understand an error.

Here the code:

```
param n, integer, >= 3;
/* number of nodes */

param MAX_TIME := 600;
param MAX_X :=20;
param maxspeed := 1;

set CITIES := 1..n;
/* set of nodes */

param p{CITIES};
param a{CITIES};
param b{CITIES};

set ARCS, within CITIES cross CITIES;
/* set of arcs */

param DIST{(i,j) in ARCS};
/* distance from node i to node j */
param NEXTC, integer, >= 0;
/* Next city after i in the solution */
var x{(i,j) in ARCS}, binary;
/* x[i,j] = 1 means that the salesman goes from node i to node j */


param bigM := 5000;
var tar{CITIES};         /*arrival */
var tlv{CITIES};         /* departure */
var tea{CITIES} >= 0;    /* early arrival (arrival before the designated   time window) */
var tla{CITIES} >= 0;    /* late arrival (arrival after the designated time window) */
var ted{CITIES} >= 0;    /* early departure (departure before the designated time window) */
var tld{CITIES} >= 0;    /* late departure (departure after the designated time window) */

set days := 1..5;
param root := 1;



var y{(i,j) in ARCS}, >= 0;
/* y[i,j] is a flow through arc (i,j) */


minimize total: sum{(i,j) in ARCS} DIST[i,j] * x[i,j];

s.t. t1 {i in CITIES} : tlv[i] >= tar[i]; 
s.t. t2 {i in CITIES, j in CITIES} : tar[j] >= tlv[i] + p[i] + DIST[i,j]/maxspeed - bigM*(1-x[i,j]);
s.t. t3 {i in CITIES} : tea[i] >= a[i] - tar[i];   /* early arrival */
s.t. t4 {i in CITIES} : tla[i] >= tar[i] - b[i];   /* late arrival */
s.t. t5 {i in CITIES} : ted[i] >= a[i] - tlv[i];   /* early departure */
s.t. t6 {i in CITIES} : tld[i] >= tlv[i] - b[i];   /* late departure */


data;

param n := 9 ;

param : ARCS : DIST :=
1  2   21
1  3   8
1  4   6
1  5   10
1  6   2
1  7   4
1  8   5
1  9   5
2  1   21
2  3   18
2  4   21
2  5   23
2  6   22
2  7   20
2  8   22
2  9   25
3  1   7
3  2   16
3  4   3
3  5   9
3  6   8
3  7   4
3  8   7
3  9   9
4  1   8
4  2   18
4  3   3
4  5   10
4  6   9
4  7   6
4  8   9
4  9   11
5  1   9
5  2   25
5  3   11
5  4   9
5  6   11
5  7   8
5  8   11
5  9   13
6  1   4
6  2   23
6  3   8
6  4   7
6  5   11
6  7   5
6  8   7
6  9   8
7  1   3
7  2   20
7  3   6
7  4   5
7  5   8
7  6   4
7  8   3
7  9   8
8  1   3
8  2   20
8  3   5
8  4   4
8  5   8
8  6   5
8  7   4
8  9   7
9  1   7
9  2   24
9  3   10
9  4   8
9  5   13
9  6   7
9  7   7
9  8   6
;

param : a :=
  1  705
  2  420
  3  420
  4  420
  5  420
  6  420
  7  420
  8  420
  9  420
;

param : b :=
  1  785
  2  795
  3  725
  4  500
  5  785
  6  785
  7  430
  8  785
  9  785
;

param : p :=
  1  65
  2  55
  3  125
  4  65
  5  65
  6  65
  7  65
  8  65
  9  65
;

option solver './cplex';

solve;
```

A code get from the (magic!) Stackoverflow.

In my Kubuntu-pc, with AMPL and cplex, I see this error:

> Error at _cmdno 2 executing "solve" command (file
>   tsp_nodi_archi_costo.run, line 170, offset 2582): error processing
>   constraint t2[1,1]:
>           invalid subscript DIST[1,1]

I have an other .run files and they work good, but this no! Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that your set ARCS does not contain (1,1), (2,2), ....

Hence DIST[i,i] is undefined, and x[i,i] is an invalid index since you declared ARCS as the index set for x.

However, as suggested by the error message, your constraint t2 is indexed on {i in CITIES, j in CITIES} and the first case it's going to attempt to create is i=1, j=1, which leads to an invalid subscript.

You can probably fix this by changing the indexing in t2 to: {i in CITIES, j in CITIES: j <> i}.

edit: I noticed some other issues:

- You have a comma after "set ARCS" which shouldn't be there.
- You appear to be missing some constraints (if you try running it and check the solution, you'll see what I mean)
- You have a parameter "NEXTC" which is identified as "next city after i in the solution". Presumably this should be a var rather than a param. It also seems to be missing an index, and nothing in the rest of the program references it. This may be related to the missing constraints issue.

Comment: Hi, Geoffrey Brent , thanks for your answer!
Now I test my application but the solution is Always 0. Why?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The constraints in this model allow all your x[i,j] to be zero, which is obviously the cheapest solution. You don't have any rules that would require any of the arcs to be used. This looks like a very incomplete program - I don't see how it could ever have worked, without substantial changes. You might be best off looking for a different example instead of trying to fix this one, especially since it's missing the most complex part of the problem.